# Detect language of new files in vim (refresh syntax highlighting)

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

Whenever you open a file, vim performs a series of checks to determine the language of the file and applies the relevant syntax highlighting; first by checking the file extension, then by looking inside the file itself. Nothing new here.

When you create a new file including the file extension, e.g., `test.sql`, vim automatically highlights the SQL syntax to anything you type - again, nothing new here.

However, when you create a new file without a file extension but containing a shebang, e.g., `#!/usr/bin/env python`, it seems to be necessary to save the file and open it again for vim to apply the checks and decide that this is a python script.

My question is whether there is a vim command that triggers these checks, allowing a refresh of the highlighting in new (extensionless) files, avoiding the need to reopen the file.

Having a look at vim's documentation for [syntax-loading](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#syntax-loading) I thought I would find something useful regarding my query - unfortunately I did not.

Comment: I suspect :set ft=python will work for you in this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here are 3 different ways you can do it:

- `:set ft=python`. The down side to this approach is that you can't add it to a keyboard shortcut since it will only work with one file type (python in this example)
- `:w`+`:e` The down side with this is that you have to save the file before running the command since it reloads the file.
- `:filetype detect` This is longer to type though.

You could add the second or third option as a shortcut with `map <C-r>
:filetype detect<CR>` to your `.vimrc` to enable refreshing the file with `ctrl`+`r`

Comment: `:filetype detect` is exactly what I was looking for - I don't mind typing - many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on @KNejad's suggestion of using `:filetype detect`, here is a config setting to automatically trigger the detection when a new file with is written:

**init.vim / .vimrc**:

```
au BufWritePost * if &syntax == '' | :filetype detect | endif
```